# weird yellow artefacts when baking normals

Tags: normals, baking, error

does anyone know why this is happening to me ?
i tried normals outside, didnt help.

Edit: edited caps, and added photos, sorry new to these boards, thanks in advance :)[image]

Comment: Don't use caps please, you can [edit] the question, also upload images inline here as the question totally depends on it. Yellow on normal map usually means intersecting geometry - rays from one surface get to near surface and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

well found an answer in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw